# Radio button and check-box values saved aginast different Ids

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

i am trying to get radio button and check box values against the same id but both values are stored in two different ids.
Where is problem?
Help me

```
 $sql1 ="INSERT INTO student (name,fathername)
VALUES ('$name','$fathername')";

$sql2 = "SELECT last_insert_id() as id";

$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); //here you insert
$res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); //here you fetch the ID you inserted
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)['id'];

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,email)
VALUES ('$id','$email')"; //here you use that said ID in your second query
$res3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3); //aaand you insert

Now the problem starts from here, both values are stored against different ids.

            //For insertion multiple values of checkbox
 $sql6="INSERT INTO information (checkbox) VALUES ('" . $checkBox . "')";     

 $res6 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql6);

           //For insertion radio button value
 $sql7 ="INSERT INTO information (radio) VALUES ('" . $gender . "')";
 $res7 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);
```

if i tried to insert values like this ('$id','" . $checkBox . "') and ('$id','" . $gender . "'), it returns null values in database.

Comment: Y not in one single insert query?

Comment: INSERT INTO information (user_id,email,check box,radio)
VALUES ('$id','$email','$checkbox','$gender')

Comment: @devpro
Oh thanx!
I was running two different queries without any specific reason.
Still there is a little problem, both fields does not work with the last insert id i-e '$id'. ?

Comment: Congrats bro... Happy coding

Comment: @devpro
same to u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run multiple `INSERT` query it will insert with different ids. No need to use `INSERT` multiple queries for a single row.

**Solution:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,email,check box,radio) 
VALUES ($id,'$email','$checkbox','$gender')";
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

**UPDATE:**

You also have an issue to getting last INSERT id. You can not fetch record as:

```
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)['id'];
```

You can also get last insert Id by using PHP as:

```
$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // use after ist query.
```

**Your Modified Code:**

```
$sql1 ="INSERT INTO student (name,fathername) VALUES ('$name','$fathername')"; 

$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // will return last insert id

$query = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,email,check box,radio) VALUES ($id,'$email','$checkbox','$gender')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: u mean to say that after the line 
mysqli_query($conn,$query);
i should put your suggested line $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); ?

Comment: No no after $res1 execution I mentioned in answer @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: And remove this $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); //here you fetch the ID you inserted
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)['id'];  @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: still not working .
i am writing such a way

$sql2 = "SELECT last_insert_id() as id";
$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); //here you insert
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); //here you fetch the ID you inserted
$id = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)['id'];

Comment: Remove this $id = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)['id'];  not required my friend @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: did not work :( .
Bro, i am new on php. Kindly do not mind. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Bro, i am really confused to see that everything is working fine. What's the problem with only these two fields.
strange ! :(

Comment: Still inserting null values .

Comment: echo $query = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,email,check box,radio) VALUES ($id,'$email','$checkbox','$gender')"; exit;      use this and  share the query @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SZeeshan\nbproject\complainForm_php.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: ddown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SZeeshan\nbproject\complainForm_php.php on line 10

Comment: U didn't show yur full code for warning mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,yourvalue); need two params @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: is it really a major problem?
Because i have
    $textarea = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);

still i am getting the address into  the database

Comment: Yes in mysqli u need two params for escspe_string function @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: now when i echo my query, it shows blank screen and still there is no value stored in db :(

Comment: @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide my friend if query is not printing it means u have some issues in yur code add error_reporting and chk the errors... When u resolve yur error my solution will work .

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use at top of the file @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: Bro, for the last time please .
I added the code error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of my file but id does not shows or giving any error.
Is there any specific method to use it ?

Comment: Before error_reporting add ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: As u treated very well for last 1 hour and tries to suggest your number of opinions, i am going to rate your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Glad to help u mere bhai @bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide

Comment: error reporting to kaam nai kar raha but ab mai mazeed tung nai karu ga bhai ko . :P
God bless You my dear :)

Comment: oooooooooo paaaaaa ggggggggg !
Masla hulll ho gayaa !!
Thnx !!
I was running one query for two to three times ! :P